# Google App Script takes a very long time to parse RSS. is there anything you can do?

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, web-applications, rss

The script translates the RSS feed, but there is a problem.
The script gives an error: very high value if there is a line: `cache.put(id, rss, 3600);`
And if this line is not, it works, the feed is parsed, but oooh very long. 10 minutes to download, because of this I can not attach it to the site, hosting is not designed for such a long waiting time.
After some number of attempts to fix it, I generally began to give out in the console that exceeded the quota of 1000 per translate per day.

The code itself:

```
  function doGet() {

  var fromLang = "ru";    
  var toLang   = "en";    
  var rssFeed  = "https://theins.ru/feed.xml";  

  var feed = parseRSS(rssFeed, fromLang, toLang);      
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(feed)
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);    
}


function parseRSS(feed, fromLang, toLang) {
   
  var id = Utilities.base64Encode(feed + fromLang + toLang);
  
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  var rss   = cache.get(id);
  
  if (rss != null) {
    return rss;
  }
  
  var item, title, desc; 
  
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch(feed).getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(txt);

  var content = XmlService.getNamespace("http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/");
  var atom = XmlService.getNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

  var root = doc.getRootElement();
  var channel = root.getChild("channel");

  channel.getChild("title").setText(channel.getChild("title").getText() + " (" + toLang + ")");
  channel.getChild("language").setText(toLang);

  var link = channel.getChild("link").getText();
  link += (link.split("?")[1] ? "&":"?") + "lang=" + toLang;
  channel.getChild("link").setText(link);

  var items = channel.getChildren("item");

  for (var i in items) {
    try {
      item  = items[i];
      
      channel.removeContent(item);

      var title = item.getChild("title").getText();
      var desc  = item.getChild("description").getText();
      var guid  = item.getChild("guid").getText();
      var cont  = item.getChild("encoded", content).getText();
          
      Utilities.sleep(1000)
      title = LanguageApp.translate(title, fromLang, toLang);
      desc  = LanguageApp.translate(desc,  fromLang, toLang, {contentType: "html"});
      guid += (guid.split("?")[1] ? "&":"?") + "lang=" + toLang;
      cont  = LanguageApp.translate(cont,  fromLang, toLang, {contentType: "html"});

      item.getChild("title").setText(title);
      item.getChild("description").setText(desc);
      item.getChild("guid").setText(guid);
      item.getChild("encoded", content).setText(cont);

      channel.addContent(item);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }
  }

  var rss = XmlService.getCompactFormat().setEncoding('UTF-8').format(doc);
  cache.put(id, rss, 3600); // Cache the feed for an hour
  return rss;
}
```

Original code here: https://gist.github.com/pfefferle/834226ee0ea20093df83f3661822b4eb

Sometimes the script does not start at all, gives completely different errors, when it starts, when the error waiting, when something else.
Sometimes it gives out an empty feed.
Now it does not work at all (waiting error)

Comment: I use XmlService with RSS feeds

Comment: How can I fix this code? help me please

Comment: I'd use the debugger and the console.log()